# Using pwntools in mac

Tags: python, macos

I want to use pwntools(which is python module) in my mac. However I get error instead of pwntools. I tried all step in https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools/issues. But I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Knight/PycharmProjects/untitled/gmail.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pwn
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pwn/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .toplevel import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pwn/toplevel.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pwnlib
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pwnlib/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    importlib.import_module('.%s' % module, 'pwnlib')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pwnlib/args.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import term
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pwnlib/term/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import completer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pwnlib/term/completer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import readline
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pwnlib/term/readline.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import text
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pwnlib/term/text.py", line 115, in <module>
    sys.modules[__name__] = Module()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pwnlib/term/text.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.num_colors = termcap.get('colors', default = 8)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pwnlib/term/termcap.py", line 25, in get
    s = curses.tigetstr(cap)
_curses.error: must call (at least) setupterm() first
```

I can't understand why I can't use it.
Help me please

Comment: What caused the traceback? Some code? Installing it? Something else?

Comment: `import pwn` this part cause error. Installing was finished successfully

Answer (score 0):

You must set the following environment variables as indicated here

export TERM=linux
export TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo

[Setupterm could not find terminal, in Python program using curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485699/setupterm-could-not-find-terminal-in-python-program-using-curses)