# My program cannot find terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am making a SNAKE game and I had a problem with it not so long ago. I used a windows operating system for 'curses' instead of a Linux operating system. So I decided to get on to the computer which had Ubuntu on it but now a new error has shown up:

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/KMR/Documents/Snake Game .py", line 8, in <module>
    curses.initscr()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/curses/__init__.py", line 30, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

My code:

```
# SNAKES GAME
# Use ARROW KEYS to play, SPACE BAR for pausing/resuming and Esc Key for exiting

import curses
from curses import KEY_RIGHT, KEY_LEFT, KEY_UP, KEY_DOWN
from random import randint

curses.initscr()
win = curses.newwin(20, 60, 0, 0)
win.keypad(1)
curses.noecho()
curses.cur_set(0)
win.border(0)
win.nodelay(1)

key = KEY_RIGHT                                          # Initalizing Values
score = 5

snake = [[4,10], [4,9], [4,8]]                          # Initial snake co-ordinates
food = [10,20]                                          # First food co-ordinates                         

win.addc(food[0], food[1], '*')                             # Prints the food

while key != 27:
    win.border(0)
    win.addstr(0, 2, 'Score :' + str(score) + ' ')          # Printing 'Score' and      
    win.addstr(0, 27, ' SNAKE ')                            # 'SNAKE' strings
    win.timeout(150 - (len(snake)/5 + len(snake)/10)%120)

    prevKey = key                                           # Previous key pressed
    event = win.getch
    key = key if event == -1 else event


    if key == ord(' '):                                     # If SPACE BAR is pressed, wait for another
        key = -1                                            # one (Pause/Resume)
        while key != ord(' '):
            key = win.getch()
    key = prevKey
    continue

if key not in [KEY_LEFT, KEY_RIGHT, KEY_UP, KEY_DOWN, 27]:  # If an invalid key is pressed
    key = prevKey

    # Calculates the new coordinates of the head of the snake. NOTE: len(snake) increases.
    # This is taken care of later at [1].
    snake.insert(0, [snake[0][0] + (key == KEY_DOWN and 1) + (key == KEY_UP and -1), snake[0][1] + (key == KEY_LEFT and -1) + (key == KEY_RIGHT and 1)])

    # If snake crosses the boundaries, make it enter from the other side                
    if snake[0][0] == 0: snake[0][0] = 18
    if snake[0][1] == 0: snake[0][1] = 58
    if snake[0][0] == 19: snake[0][0] = 1
    if snake[0][1] == 59: snake[0][1] = 1

    # Exit if snake crosses the boundaries (Uncomment to enable)
    # if snake[0][0] == 0 or snake[0][0] == 19 or snake[0][1] == 0 or snake[0][1] == 59: break

    # If snake runs over itself
    def endgame():
        if snake[0]in snake[1:]: endgame()


    if snake[0] == food:
        food = []                                                                                                                           
        score += 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Futher problems with python snake game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008560/futher-problems-with-python-snake-game)

Comment: It is. Everyone was too focused on my title rather than helping ME. So I made a new question so I'd get some actual help!

Comment: @R.M.R try using some of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485699/setupterm-could-not-find-terminal-in-python-program-using-curses

Comment: @TheWrenchintheSystem Is the dup link I suggested in his original question.... >.>

Comment: Yep. But I figured I'd post it here for future people and so he will look at it.

Comment: And how are you running tis code?

Answer (score 0):

```
import curses
import subprocess

def main():
    try:
        scr = curses.initscr()
    except _curses.error:
        subprocess.call(['lxterminal', '--command', 'python', __file__])
    else:
        run_normal_code(scr) #execute  above code in this block
```

Comment: This may well solve the OP's problem, but you should explain what you are doing and why. If you have the same problem but you don't have `lxterminal`, for example, a beginner might not understand how to fix it.