# Error Getting while executing Python Script from cron job

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Getting below error while executing python script using cron job

```
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485699/setupterm-could-not-find-terminal-in-python-program-using-curses